# enter parameter value while insert value in vba Form

Tags: ms-access

I want to insert `Employee Id` but every time the `Window` appears.

> Enter Parameter Value Ad001

Ad001 is the value of `me.mstrEMpID`.

This is my procedure:

```vb
Dim db
Dim tmpempid As String
tmpempid = (Me.mstrEmpID)
sqlqry1 = "INSERT INTO Timesheet ([StrEMPId]) VALUES ( TmpEmpId );"
DoCmd.OpenTable "Timesheet"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlqry1
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: "but every time the Window appears"... what happens? please rephrase and add missing details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use string concatenation and delimiters, like this:

```
Dim tmpempid As String
tmpempid = (Me.mstrEmpID)
sqlqry1 = "INSERT INTO Timesheet ([StrEMPId]) VALUES ( '" & tmpempid & "');"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlqry1
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Or do it properly, and use parameters:

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO Timesheet ([StrEMPId]) VALUES (?);")
    .Parameters(0) = Me.mstrEmpID
    .Execute
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value to create the SQL command:

```
sqlqry1 = "INSERT INTO Timesheet ([StrEMPId]) VALUES (" & TmpEmpId & ");"
```

For two parameters:

```
sqlqry1 = "INSERT INTO Timesheet ([StrEMPId], [Ad002]) VALUES (" & TmpEmpId & ", " & ValueForAd002 & ");"
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But I already tried this but the same result asking Enter Parameter Value Ad002

Comment: Then the table has a field Ad002 which needs to have a value passed as well. See edited answer.

Comment: There are two fields only.   ADVDAte  - Date/time, StrEmpID - Text

Comment: It should be Ad001, sorry, but it doesn't change the fact, that somewhere in your table/query, a field or parameter with that name exists and needs to be addressed.

Comment: In the form TextBox, whatever data, I input it asked the same DAta as Parameter Value. E.g If I enter Value AD001 it asked AD001 Parameter Value, If I enter AD002, It asked Parameter Value of AD002.

Comment: Oh. Then you haven't adopted the syntax in my code. Your original will work as you describe.

Comment: Yes, I use Your Syntax with & TmpEmpId &. But same result.